# Getting text line by line from EditTexts and TextViews

Tags: android, string, arraylist, android-edittext, textview

I have a table that has dynamically added rows with `EditText`'s and `TextView`'s. I managed to get the texts from these boxes and write it to a .txt file. I used `ArrayList`'s like

```
ArrayList<TextView> allTimes = new ArrayList<TextView>();
ArrayList<EditText> allNumber = new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

and added the content of textboxes like

```
TextView dt = new TextView(this);
allDates.add(dt);
EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
allNumber.add(et3);
```

then I combined them into one string array

```
String[] stringsDat = new String[allDates.size()];
String[] stringsNum = new String[allNumber.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < allDates.size(); i++) {
   stringsDat[i] = allDates.get(i).getText().toString();
   stringsNum[i] = allNumber.get(i).getText().toString();
}

List<String> stringsAll = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.addAll(stringsAll, stringsDat);
Collections.addAll(stringsAll, stringsNum);

String[] finalArray = stringsAll.toArray(new String[stringsAll.size()]);
```

then saved as a txt file with `FileWriter`

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(getExternalStorageDirectory() + "sample.txt");
for (String stringsAllAll : finalArray) {
writer.write(stringsAllAll);
}
```

It works fine but my problem is that I get the texts in one line after each other. I need them line by line for example:

It looks like this now:

> 2016-12-27 2016-12-27 2016-12-27 2016-12-27 2016-12-27 41 12 33 66 59

and it should look like this

> 2016-12-27 41
>
> 2016-12-27 12
>
> 2016-12-27 33
>
> 2016-12-27 66
>
> 2016-12-27 59

So, is there a way to do this? Or is this a bad approach? It would be easier to get the content of each `TableRow`, but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add line break while writing data in your file. I am assuming your both arrays(stringsDat and stringsNum) have same number of data.

```
for(int count = 0 ; count < stringsDat.length() ; count++) {
   // Output will be - 2016-12-27 41 
   writer.write(stringsDat[i] + " " + stringsNum[i] + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split().`

```
String multiLines = edittext.getText().toString();
String delimiter = "\n";
```

OR any delimiter you think need, spacebar, underscore, etc.

```
streets = multiLines.split(delimiter);
```